# If you backup your iPhone using iTunes, is it a full backup even if on the iCloud settings it's not?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup

I only have 5 GB of iCloud storage. So my iCloud backup settings on my iPhone, i didn't include Photos (cause I have 6 GB worth of photos).

Now if I wanna do a full backup of my iPhone, does the [manually backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAVqD.jpg) option on iTunes work?

Will it be a full backup? I checked the backup size on my Mac and it says 7 GB, so is it safe to assume that it was a full backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "full" in the sense that everything that is ACTUALLY on your device is backed up (minus payment and password/security settings for obvious security reasons), but it is NOT full in the sense that not everything you see on your device is truly "on" your device. Some stuff is merely just a shortcut (for the sake of a longer explanation) to items stored in iCloud.  The details and differences of iCloud and iTunes -based backups, along with what is excluded (such as those shortcuts) in an iTunes backup are documented [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136), courtesy of Apple, on their support site.

Comment: By "full" I meant the "full backup" made on the phone settings' icloud backup when you check all the things that could be backed up. This includes the photos.

Comment: I know what a full backup is. Read the document and it will tell you what is excluded. If it's not excluded, it's INcluded.

Comment: I read the apple documentation and on the itunes backup it doesnt include "My Photo Stream". are these my photos on my device?

Comment: @J.Mangum My Photo Stream keeps the images on iCloud so they are not a part of the backup unless you've specifically downloaded/saved any of those images to your device.

Comment: Got it. i dont use photo stream so the itunes backup includes my photos. The backup is 7gb worth so its safe to assume it includes the photos right?

Comment: @J.Mangum Yes.  If you really want to test it out, though, you could always back up your photos to iCloud or Google Photos (which is completely free if you let it scale down your photos a bit), or Amazon Photos, and then restore your backup to see if the photos are still there (which they will be). In case something goes awry you can just restore the photos from iCloud or Google Photos (or whatever else you chose).

Comment: FYI, the article I had linked specifically says that My Photo Stream is excluded in iTunes backups.

Comment: I actually have all my photos backed up in google photos! But i wanna back it up using itunes so its easier to restore it i guess.

Comment: @J.Mangum Cool. So, if my answer was adequate please up vote my response and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @J.Mangum I added more detail to my answer to make it a little clearer.